# Unable to create custom performance counters in Azure Web Role

Tags: azure, performancecounter, azure-web-roles

When trying to create custom performance counters as explained [in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411517.aspx), I still get a security exception.

The code I am using is the same as in that article, only I am creating a different counters.

I understand that I can try to create it in a start-up task, but for now I want to do it inside the role.. it should work :/

The exception:

```
[SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.]
   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable) +12746267
   System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CreateRegistryEntry(String categoryName, PerformanceCounterCategoryType categoryType, CounterCreationDataCollection creationData, Boolean& iniRegistered) +170
   System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.RegisterCategory(String categoryName, PerformanceCounterCategoryType categoryType, String categoryHelp, CounterCreationDataCollection creationData) +49
   System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(String categoryName, String categoryHelp, PerformanceCounterCategoryType categoryType, CounterCreationDataCollection counterData) +558
```

The beginning of my ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="Jonathan.Cloud" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WebRole name="WebDriver" vmsize="Small" enableNativeCodeExecution="true">
    <Runtime executionContext="elevated" />
```

When I RDP into the role, I can see that the application pool is still running with the NetworkService identity, was expecting it to run under a different principal as I changed the role to be 'elevated' - manually setting up a custom principal with permissions solves this, but it will be over-ridden once the role reconfigure itself or if I deploy an upgrade - in any case, this is not really a solution but a hack :/ [frustrated]

Comment: have you tried using the Windows Azure Powershell Cmdlets instead of wrapping the management API yourself? Here is an article by David Aiken on how to configure Diagnostic information remotely with PowerShell. http://www.davidaiken.com/2011/10/18/how-to-easily-enable-windows-azure-diagnostics-remotely/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of Web Role of Full IIS, the special privilege which you appointed in Runtime element is applied to RoleEntoryPoint. I think that it is necessary to register a custom performance counter by inner RoleEntryPoint (usually WebRole.cs) OnStart method.

Comment: You are correct, that worked! :) I moved the code that initializes the counters to OnStart() of RoleEntryPoint, deleted the existing deployment to ensure that I start clean, and published it - works and registered the counters.

Comment: Remember also to include the <Runtime executionContext="elevated" /> configuration in your .csdef file (as in your example)